# creating setup for mac application

Tags: macos, installation

Hai all,
  I have created a new mac application using xcode.Now I need to create a setup to install the application ..Is there any tool to create a setup file???.Looking forwrd for reply....

Answer (score 2):

You can just zip up the application and distribute it that way. Or you can use a dmg file ([instructions including encryption](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1578)).

If you really need to do some funky processing in the install, use [Package Maker](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Mac apps are folders that you copy into the `/Applications` directory.  You just need to put your `.app` folder into a `.dmg` image.